Duplicated queries when using relations and assets
I have this setup:
{% for entry in craft.entries().section('mySection').with(['relation.image']).all()
  {% set relation = entry.relation.one() %}
  {% set image = relation.image.one() %}
  {{ entry.title }} etc
{% endfor %}

As part of this, Entry 1 and Entry 5 have the same relation (and therefore the same image) and the debug toolbar is telling me I have duplicate queries -- it's getting the same image twice.
It doesn't seem to have a massive impact on performance, but I'm trying to optimise as much as possible. Is there a way to avoid this and, say, cache the image somehow?
